# Java equivalent of JavaScript Date.UTC

Tags: javascript, java, utc

Java equivalent of JavaScript Date.UTC(1980, 0, 8)

Example in JavaScript :

```js
var base_date = Date.UTC(1980, 0, 8);
console.log("base_date:" + base_date)
```

The result is: `base_date:316137600000`

How to do it in Java and the the exact same result?

The next java code, gives another result than javascript:

```java
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.TimeZone;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
     Calendar cal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        cal.set(1980, 0, 8);
        long time = cal.getTimeInMillis();
        System.out.println(time);
        System.out.println(cal.getTime().getTime());
    }
}
```

`316185175487`

`316185175487`